# Add user to server role in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, roles

I am trying to add a user to a SQL Server role using PowerShell.

I have a script which reads the server, user and role information and puts it in a text file. I am able to connect to the server and check for the user availability in that server, however I am not able to add the server role to the user. Please assist with the correct script to add the role. My script is long and not able to put it here. Is there a way I can attach it as a text file?

Comment: https://ws.onehub.com/workspaces/1140646/files

Comment: Hi Imran. I have shared the file. Please check and assist.

Comment: Hi, I am still having trouble adding the user to the server role and would appreciate any assistance. File has been shared in the link mentioned above.

Comment: @ArvindAryans, add the PowerShell code you've tried you your question. You should be able to execute a SQL Command like `ALTER SERVER ROLE [ServerRoleName] ADD MEMBER [UserLoginName];`.

Comment: @ArvindAryans, I added Bounty on your question, See it and mark Accept to answer as per your needs so I will give bounty to that answer

Answer (score 3):

The Add-UserToRole function takes four parameters Server, Database, User and Role and does a series of error checks.

suppose you have the following files with user information

[image]
[image]

and use them with the Add-SQLAccountToSQLRole and Add-UserToRole functions to create the users. try this

[image]

Powershell result will be as follows

[image]

Check [Here](https://sqldbawithabeard.com/2013/09/23/add-user-to-database-role-with-powershell/) for more details and complete code

Comment: @yivi I have added the relevant details from the original post

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple listing [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9cea5eb3-3d15-4ca6-bb05-86a57240c426/add-domain-user-as-sysadmin-in-sql-server-2012-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell).

This uses a Windows domain user, but there is no reason it shouldn't work for SQL Server users as well. Anyway, here goes:

```
$sqlSrv = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' "SQLServer\Instance"

$login = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login -ArgumentList $sqlSrv, "DOMAIN\username"
$login.LoginType = "WindowsUser"

$login.AddToRole("MyServerRole")
$login.Alter()
```

If you also need to create the login in the same script (I don't think that's the OP's case), you'll just add `$login.Create()` before the `AddToRole` call.